# Why is my ExpressJS req.query not working?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, express

I have a NodeJS repl, which has an input, button, and h1 element. When you press the button, the HTML inside of the h1 element will replace with the value of the input. Here is my code:

index.js:

```
const Database = require("@replit/database");
const db = new Database();
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/ajaxcall", async function(req, res) {
// db.set("this works?", "it does").then(() => {console.log(db.get("this works?"))});
res.send(req.query.keyUse);
})

app.get('/:id', function(request, response){
   fs.readFile(`${request.url == '/ajaxcall' ? '/ajaxcall' : String(request.url).substring(1)}`, null, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write('File not found!');
        } else {
          response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
});

app.listen(8000);
// http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="replace">meep</h1>
  <input id="getkey">
  <button id="button" onclick="get()">get</button>

  <script>
    function get() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: `https://databasetest.aquarial.repl.co/ajaxcall?keyUse=${document.querySelector('#getkey').value}`,
        dataType: 'json',
      })
      .done(function (data) {
        console.log('Response:', JSON.stringify(data, "", 2));
        $('#replace').html(JSON.stringify(data, "", 2));
      })
      .fail(function (jqXJR, textStatus, err) {
        console.log('Error:', textStatus);
      })
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Except when I hit "get", nothing happens. I don't even get an error. Why not?
[Here is the repl, if you need it.](https://replit.com/@Aquarial/databasetest)

Comment: Can you log `req.query` object?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. The AJAX was set to receiving JSON data, not a string. It needed to be like:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: `https://databasetest.aquarial.repl.co/ajaxcall?keyUse=${document.querySelector('#getkey').value}`,
        dataType: 'text',
      })
```